# Cannot convert column when using FeatureTools to normalize_entity with timestamps

Tags: featuretools

I'm attempting to use FeatureTools to normalize a table for feature synthesis. My table is similar to Max-Kanter's response from [How to apply Deep Feature Synthesis to a single table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50145953/how-to-apply-deep-feature-synthesis-to-a-single-table). I'm hitting an exception I would appreciate some help working around.

The exception originates in `featuretools.entityset.entity.entityset_convert_variable_type`, which doesn't seem to handle time types.

What is the nature of the exception, and can I work around it?

The Table, `df`:

```
PatientId | AppointmentID | Gender | ScheduledDay | AppointmentDay | Age | Neighbourhood | Scholarship | Hipertension | Diabetes | Alcoholism | Handcap | SMS_received | No-show
12345     | 5642903       | F     | 2016-04-29    | 2016-04-29     | 62  | JARDIM DA     | 0           | 1            | 0        | 0          | 0       | 0            | No
67890     | 3902943       | M     | 2016-03-18    | 2016-04-29     | 44  | Other Nbh     | 1           | 1            | 0        | 0          | 0       | 0            | Yes
...
```

My Code:

```
appointment_entity_set = ft.EntitySet('appointments')
appointment_entity_set.entity_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=df, entity_id='appointments',
    index='AppointmentID', time_index='AppointmentDay')

# error generated here
appointment_entity_set.normalize_entity(base_entity_id='appointments',
    new_entity_id='patients',
    index='PatientId')
```

ScheduledDay and AppointmentDay are type `pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp` as is the case in [Max-Kanter's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50145953/how-to-apply-deep-feature-synthesis-to-a-single-table).

The Exception:

```
~/.virtualenvs/trane/lib/python3.6/site-packages/featuretools/entityset/entity.py in entityset_convert_variable_type(self, column_id, new_type, **kwargs)
    474         df = self.df
--> 475         if df[column_id].empty:
    476             return
    477         if new_type == vtypes.Numeric:

Exception: Cannot convert column first_appointments_time to <class 'featuretools.variable_types.variable.DatetimeTimeIndex'>
```

featuretools==0.1.21

*This dataset is from the [Kaggle Show or No Show competition](https://www.kaggle.com/jchen2186/show-or-no-show-visualization-and-prediction/notebook)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error that’s showing up seems to be a problem with the way the `AppointmentDay` variable is being read by pandas. We actually have an example [Kaggle kernel](https://www.kaggle.com/sjrothsc/using-featuretools-for-missed-appointments) with that dataset. There, we needed to use `pandas.read_csv` with `parse_dates`:

```
data = pd.read_csv("data/KaggleV2-May-2016.csv", parse_dates=['AppointmentDay', 'ScheduledDay'])
```

That returns a pandas Series whose values are of type `numpy.datetime64`. This should load in fine to Featuretools.

Also, can you make sure you have the latest version of Featuretools from pip? There is a set trace command in that stack trace that isn’t in the latest release.

Comment: Thank you, @max-kanter. That was perfect. Also, thanks for pointing out the example. I had no idea.

I deleted the `pdb` line. Sorry about that. I'd introduced it locally to see what was going on.